# Reading serialized objects from a binary file in java?

Tags: java, file-io, binaryfiles

I have a simple question.

How to read all the contents of the binary file in java ?

I wrote some code but it only retrieves the first object.

Here is my code:

```
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\student.bin"));
    Binary b2 = (Binary)in.readObject();
    System.out.println("Student ID: " + b2.id);
    System.out.println("Student Name: " + b2.name);
    System.out.println("Student Grade: " + b2.grade);
    in.close();
```

Comment: Is there more than one object? If there is, than you would want to deserialize as a `List` like so: `List<Binary> binaries = (List)in.readObject();`. If the object is not some form of list, then only one Object is present in the file

Comment: You should edit your title to mention you are reading serialized objects rather than any binary data

Comment: Copy and paste the 4 middle lines as many times as there are users in the file. Or, more seriously, use a loop.

Comment: how to loop in a binary file ???

Comment: Do you know how many users there are in the file? If so, use `for (int i = 0; i < numberOfUsers; i++)`. If you don't, then use an infinite loop, and break from it as soon as an IOException is thrown by readObject() because the end of the stream is reached. But in that case, it would probably be a better idea to save/load a single List<Binary>, as malinator suggests.

Comment: 'How to loop in a binary file' doesn't make sense. You just put your reading code into a loop. 'In a binary file' has nothing to do with it. Hard to see what the  problem is.

Answer (score 2):

As malinator mentionned, it is bad practice to concatenate serialized objects in a single file, they should be contained in a Collection.

If you do not have access to the code producing the file, there can be 2 situations :

- either you know the number of objects, then you can do the right number of `ObjectInputStream.readObject()` calls, preferably with a `for` loop
- or you don't, then the problem is detecting the end of the file. You could use a `while` loop coupled with a `try/catch(EOFException)`.

Comment: It should be `catch (EOFException)`, and it isn't bad practice, it is how the API is designed to be used.

Comment: Of course I'm sure. That's what `EOFException` is *for.* To signal end of file. End Of File.