# Deserialize many objects in java?

Tags: java, serialization, file-io, deserialization

I have a question. now i serialize many objects in a binary file called student.bin

after adding object data in the binary file now i want to retrieve all the data written in the binary file.

but it only retrieve the first object data.

the question is: how to get all contents of the file?

here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Binary implements Serializable{

public int id;
public String name;
public int grade;

public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    Binary b = new Binary();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("Enter student id: ");
    b.id = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.printf("Enter student name: ");
    b.name = sc.next();
    System.out.printf("Enter student grade: ");
    b.grade = sc.nextInt();
    ObjectOutputStream bin = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\student.bin",true));
    bin.writeObject(b);
    bin.close();

    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\student.bin"));
    Binary b2 = (Binary)in.readObject();
    System.out.println("Student ID: " + b2.id);
    System.out.println("Student Name: " + b2.name);
    System.out.println("Student Grade: " + b2.grade);
    in.close();

}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a while loop. Streams have a `hasNext` method which will let you keep reading objects as long as there are unread bytes in the file. Note that if the file has extra bytes at the end, this will cause an error.

```
List<Binary> binaries = new ArrayList<Binary>();
while(in.hasNext()) {
    binaries.add((Binary) in.readObject());
}
```

I apologise if this is invalid, I don't have access to test it right now.

Edit: It's possible `hasNext` is a method of Scanner rather than Stream, in which case you'd have to wrap the Stream in a Scanner object: `Scanner read = new Scanner(in)`.

Comment: thanks for you answer but how to print the elements???

Comment: you didn't answer the full question. i want to print all the objects data separately... for example if i have object data like this(1,"John",50) so it should be printed like my output statement i wrote in my code above. each object data must be separately printed.

Comment: Input streams don't have `hasNext()` methods, and you can't use a `Scanner` and an `ObjectInputStream` at the same time on the same underlying stream. You haven't tried this.

Comment: @EJP can you help me please, i wanna answer for my question. i took a long hours for finding an answer.

Comment: @BeginnerProgrammer You were *given* [several answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33924112/207421) in your duplicated question.